# Can the gears on an electric towne 8 be changed to higher

Tags: gears

Wife bought a Towne 8 Electric bike.  Can the gears be exchanged for higher ratio

Comment: Can you add a link to a page that has specs of the bike drivetrain? If not can you add photos of the rear hub area including the derailleur (if there is one) and tee crank?

Comment: Please also give specific information about the exact make and model of the bike. A web search for "towne 8 electric bike" turned up no exact match. Do you mean the Electra Townie 8? And if so, do you mean their electric motorized version, or the conventional version? In either case, which model _exactly_ are you asking about, and what year was the bicycle built? They have more than one drivetrain option available for their models, and there may be differences over different years. (Of course, the details for the drivetrain are key, but if you can't provide those, exact bike info would help).

Comment: Are you comfortable with hand tools?  Are you prepared to attempt this work yourself ?    And could you clarify if "higher" means harder or easier, bigger or smaller  (gearing names can be confusing.)

Comment: The images I can find online show what appears to be a relatively standard 1x8 derailleur drive: Shimano Tourney 8-Speed rear derailer, Scram PG-820 11-32 8 speed cog array.  Doesn't say whether it's freewheel or freehub (probably freehub, since it's disk), and there are several possible "gotchas" when doing upgrades, but it would appear doable in general.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming by 'higher ratio' you mean increasing the top speed, a "harder" gear.)

You cannot really make the gearing higher on that bike, no.

You already have an 11-tooth smallest cog in the rear which is the smallest 'normal' cog available on an 8 speed bike.

The 38-tooth chain ring in the front is an integral part of the Bosch Drive system and 38T is the largest one available.

So it is not practical to make the rear gear smaller or the front gear larger with off the shelf parts.

(If by "higher ratio" gear you mean an "easier" gear: then yes a bike shop could swap in a cassette with an 'easier' gear, but note your Bosch bike senses torque in addition to cadence so the motor might also help you proportionally less depending on circumstances.)

Comment: (and for older models that have the 'mini' bosch chain rings I'm pretty sure electra still always used the biggest ones available, but couldn't swear to it.)